# Mongoose multi populate match?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I would like match many populates:

```
let data = await Post.find().sort('-created')
    .populate({path: 'user', select: '_id username avatar_small', match: { username: { "$regex": query, "$options": ['i', 'g'] }}})
    .populate({path: 'passion', select: '_id name name_proc', match: { name: { "$regex": query, "$options": ['i', 'g'] }}})
    .lean().skip(skip).limit(30).exec();
```

This only works with one populate but not with many and it also skips if populate doesn't exist.

Comment: well populate is not a good option to extract data from different collection... You should use `$lookup` aggregation here

Comment: ok thx i look this